# Why is "Hello world!" used as the default text in LaTeX?

Tags: wysiwyg

I always see it everywhere - is it just random and something that has stuck but chance? To me, its like "hello world" as in you are entering a new world of typesetting that's not WYSIWYG

Comment: https://www.thesoftwareguild.com/blog/the-history-of-hello-world/#:~:text=Traditionally%2C%20Hello%20World%20programs%20are,World%20both%20easily%20and%20correctly.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/602237/where-does-hello-world-come-from

Comment: See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Obfuscated_C_Code_Contest

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It actually predates LaTeX and goes back to Kernighan and Ritchie's *C Programming Language* in which the first program presented outputs the words "hello, world."

More information is available at [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%22Hello,_World!%22_program).